# ClassNotFoundException during wildfly-swarm startup

Tags: wildfly-swarm

I am getting an issue while trying to run Wildfly Swarm. Following is the error.

```
org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from modules/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/impl/module.xml
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:228)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder.findModule(BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder.java:58)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.findModule(ModuleLoader.java:439)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:342)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:289)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addExportedPaths(Module.java:1230)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addExportedPaths(Module.java:1278)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addExportedPaths(Module.java:1278)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1122)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1449)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1477)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:225)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.getMainClass(MainInvoker.java:76)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.<init>(MainInvoker.java:35)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:44)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:35)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to add artifact 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss:2.0.0-alpha-9' (position: END_TAG seen ...rap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss:2.0.0-alpha-9"/>... @15:104) caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseArtifact(ModuleXmlParser.java:836)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseResources(ModuleXmlParser.java:739)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleContents(ModuleXmlParser.java:535)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:340)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:226)
    ... 15 more
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.getMainClass(MainInvoker.java:81)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.<init>(MainInvoker.java:35)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:44)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:35)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.getMainClass(MainInvoker.java:81)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.<init>(MainInvoker.java:35)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:44)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

And following is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.research</groupId>
  <artifactId>indexer</artifactId>
  <name>WildFly Swarm Example</name>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <version.wildfly.swarm>2017.2.0</version.wildfly.swarm>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
        <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <finalName>demo</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Java EE 7 dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- WildFly Swarm Fractions -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Had tried cleaning maven repo a couple of times. But nothing helped. Please help. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: try different version  <version.wildfly.swarm>2017.1.1</version.wildfly.swarm> and see if the error still exits

Comment: @ravthiru I had tried 2016.10.0 but still the error exists

Comment: Are you able to figure out the issue?

Comment: @ravthiru No! I had tried all possible ways. But all that had just failed